# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server after uninstalling and reinstalling apache2 on Raspbian

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, apache2

I uninstalled apache, php, mysql, proftpd, wordpress, cerbot and letsencrypt to get a new, fresh install of apache.

After uninstalling all packages and reinstalling apache, i got this error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "restart" failed.
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-08-28 15:46:46 CEST; 23ms ago
     Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
  Process: 10693 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 28 15:46:46 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Aug 28 15:46:46 raspberrypi apachectl[10693]: apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 33 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf: No such file or directory
Aug 28 15:46:46 raspberrypi apachectl[10693]: Action 'start' failed.
Aug 28 15:46:46 raspberrypi apachectl[10693]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Aug 28 15:46:46 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 28 15:46:46 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 28 15:46:46 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (241-7~deb10u8+rpi1) ...
```

I tried to remove all apache-related packages by

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
sudo apt autoremove
```

but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You have an typing error on line 225 of file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: I deleted the directory /etc/apache2, because i hoped this would fix my problem, when installing apache again. 
But now it says:
`Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: No such file or directory`
Shouldn't the directory be created when installing apache?

Answer (score 0):

I flashed a new image onto the Pi because I couldn't make it run.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.